# Ionic Google social authentication to Django Rest Framework backend

Tags: django, cordova, ionic-framework, python-social-auth, django-rest-framework

I am trying to get social authentication working for my mobile app (an Ionic app on Android). Django rest framework backend with **rest_framework_jwt**, **social_django**, and **rest_social_auth**.

On my Ionic app I was using [satellizer.js](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer), however, I can't use InAppBrowser so now I am trying to do the following with **cordova-plugin-googleplus**:

**Step#1** ***(On client/app)***

```
if (provider == 'google') {
    // Use Google API Natively to get tokens and user info  
    window.plugins.googleplus.login(
                {
                    // TODO Get the WebClient from App settings
                  'webClientId': '[*.myclientid]', // optional clientId of your Web application from Credentials settings of your project - On Android, this MUST be included to get an idToken. On iOS, it is not required.
                  'offline': true, // optional, but requires the webClientId - if set to true the plugin will also return a serverAuthCode, which can be used to grant offline access to a non-Google server
                }) ................
```

**Result:** This gets me a valid response with both a **idToken**, **serverAuthCode**, and a **userId**.

**Step#2**

I am not sure what the next step is. Originally, I was going to try using Django **rest_social_auth** to do the following from my client/app:

`POST /api/login/social/`

*with data (json)*

`provider=google&code=ASLKDJASLDKJASLD`

Which was supposed to return a JWT token ([from my understanding of the docs](https://github.com/st4lk/django-rest-social-auth#user-content-oauth-20-workflow-with-rest-social-auth)), however, it is not passing the `JWTAuthMixin` as there is no value returned from a call to `get_authorization_header(request).split()` in that Mixin. These means that nothing is returned to my client/app except a 400 error.

**Am I supposed to be adding a header to my Ionic app POST when passing my idToken or serverAuthCode?** Or am I on the wrong side of the tracks...

Are there any implementation recommendations for this auth flow?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far I did the following and it works.

**1. On app/client**

(*The client uses **satellizer.js** and the **cordova-plugin-googleplus***)

```
if (provider == 'google') {
            // Use Google API Natively to get tokens and user info  
            window.plugins.googleplus.login(
                    {
                        // TODO Get the WebClient from App settings
                      'webClientId': '*[googleclientid]*.apps.googleusercontent.com',
                      'offline': true
                    },
                    function (obj) {
                        $http.post(SERVER.url + '[MY BACKEND URL]' + '/google-oauth2/', {code: obj.idToken, servAuthCode: obj.serverAuthCode})
                          .success(function(data){
                            $auth.setToken(data.jwt_token);
                            /.. Do something ../
                          })
                          .error(function(data){
                             console.log("There was an error" + JSON.stringify(data)); 
                          });                       
                    },
                    function (msg) {
                        // TODO Set Error states
                        console.error('error: ' + msg);
                    }

                );
        }
```

**Summary**

- The app calls the Google plus API `googleplus.login` method (sending my webClientId)
- I post the resulting idToken and serverAuthCode obtained from google after login to my Django backend.

**2. My backend methods**

***URL***

My app/client hits the `url(r'^[MY BACKEND URL]/(?P<backend>[\w-]+)/$', ObtainAuthToken.as_view(), ),`

***View***

This calls the following view and functions:

```
class ObtainAuthToken(APIView):
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)

    def post(self, request, backend):

        data = request.data
        user_tokenID = data['code']
        server_auth_code = data['servAuthCode']

        if user_tokenID and server_auth_code and verify_google_user_token_ID(user_tokenID):

            # Get Google OAuth credentials for the verified GOOGLE user.
            credentials = settings.GOOGLE_FLOW.step2_exchange(server_auth_code)

            # Here we call PSA to authenticate like we would if we used PSA on server side.
            user = register_by_access_token(request, backend, token=credentials.access_token)

            # If user is active we get or create the REST token and send it back with user data
            if user and user.is_active:
                # Generate JWT token for user and pass back to client
                jwt_payload_handler = api_settings.JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER
                jwt_encode_handler = api_settings.JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER

                payload = jwt_payload_handler(user)
                token = jwt_encode_handler(payload)

                return JsonResponse({'id': user.id, 'name': user.username, 'jwt_token': token})

        return JsonResponse({'status':'false','error':'Bad Credentials, check the Access Token and/or the UID'},
                            status=403)


def verify_google_user_token_ID(user_tokenID):
    try:
        google_http_request = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()

        idinfo = verify_token(user_tokenID, request=google_http_request,
                 audience=settings.SOCIAL_AUTH_GOOGLE_OAUTH2_FULL_KEY)

        # Or, if multiple clients access the backend server:
        if idinfo['aud'] not in [settings.GOOGLE_APP_ID_ANDROID, settings.GOOGLE_APP_ID_WEB]:
           raise crypt.AppIdentityError("Unrecognized client.")

        if idinfo['iss'] not in ['accounts.google.com', 'https://accounts.google.com']:
            raise crypt.AppIdentityError("Wrong issuer.")

        return True

    except crypt.AppIdentityError as e:
        # Invalid token
        return False


@psa('social:complete')
def register_by_access_token(request, backend, token):
    backend = social_core.backends.google.GoogleOAuth2()
    user = backend.do_auth(access_token=token, backend=backend)

    if user:
        return user
    else:
        return None
```

***3. Back on the client***

My client then looks at the response and takes the returned JWT and loads it to memory with `$auth.setToken(data.jwt_token);`

I think this works for now, but I still have to deal with token refresh and revocation etc.